# Override snowflake-connector-python output type handler

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector

I have a sql which queries a column having type NUMBER(38,18) in Snowflake. When I execute the query using  the below

```
snowflake_cursor.execute(sql)
df = snowflake_cursor.fetch_pandas_all()
```

The type of that column in dataframe is decimal.Decimal. Is there a way to override so that it is float every time. I don't want to do any casting in SQL.

I found this function in the code of snowflake-connector-python (src/snowflake/connector/converter.py)

```
    def _FIXED_to_python(self, ctx):
        return int if ctx["scale"] == 0 else decimal.Decimal
```

**Version - 2.7.2**

Comment: what version of the snowflake-connector-python are you running?

Comment: @SimonD I'm using 2.7.2